# Add custom ToolbarOptions for selected text in Flutter

Tags: flutter

By default ToolbarOptions contains copy, cut, paste, selectAll options. Can we add a custom action? For example, an action which will keep the selected text and remove unselected one.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible in flutter, you can only control show or don't show default actions by the `toolbarOptions` property of `TextField`.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/55895) on github to add this functionality but it's not fully done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selectable to customize the toolbar options and assign actions upon press. You can also grab the selected text.

https://pub.dev/packages/selectable